# How do i make this loop if its a tie?

Tags: python

Im trying to make my program loop if both computer and human draw the same card it is my game of war i am developing and if both land on the same card i want the program to loop over and draw more cards until the tie is broke! i got it to a new stage but get an error when i run this on pycharm, not sure

what is wrong this time it looks to be ok, i changed all of the values instead of printing it nows sets the value then prints later on in the program

```
import random
while True:
cardValue = random.randint(2,14)
cardSuit = random.randint (0,3)
humanCard = random.randint (2,14)
humanSuit = random.randint (0,3)


if cardValue == 14:
    print ("Ace")
elif cardValue == 13:
    print ("King")
elif cardValue == 12:
    print ("Queen")
elif cardValue == 11:
    print ("Jack")
elif cardValue < 10:
    print (cardValue)

if cardSuit == 0:
    print ("Spades")
elif cardSuit == 1:
    print ("Diamonds")
elif cardSuit ==2:
    print ("Hearts")
elif cardSuit == 3:
    print *"Clubs"


if humanCard == 14:
    print ("Ace")
elif humanCard == 13:
    print ("King")
elif humanCard == 12:
    print ("Queen")
elif humanCard == 11:
    print ("Jack")
elif humanCard < 10:
    print (cardValue)

if humanSuit == 0:
    print ("Spades")
elif humanSuit == 1:
    print ("Diamonds")
elif humanSuit == 2:
    print ("Hearts")
elif humanSuit ==3:
    print ("Clubs")


if humanCard > cardValue:
    print("Human Wins!")
    break
elif humanCard < cardValue:
    print('Computer Wins!')
    break
else:
    print ('Its a draw!')
    while True:
        continue
```

Comment: I would suggest encapsulating your code inside a function and then calling it recursively in the humanCard==cardValue case. Return a value from the recursive function if you need to keep track of how many ties you get.

Comment: Did you even take a look at the tags you put on this question? `war` - web application archive, `tie` - perl command. Do you think those tags were applicable to your question?

Comment: You seem to know about `while True`, so use it around **all your code**. `break` when it should stop

Comment: @David i dont really understand that, what is a function?

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way (requires python 3.6 because of the `f-strings` on the print's):

```
import random

suits        = ['Spades', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Clubs']
cards        = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','Jack','Queen','King','Ace']
cards_values = [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]

map_cards_values = dict(zip(cards,cards_values))
end_game = False

while not end_game:
    aiCard    = random.choice(cards)
    aiSuit    = random.choice(suits)
    humanCard = random.choice(cards)
    humanSuit = random.choice(suits)

    print(f"AI card is a {aiCard} of {aiSuit}")
    print(f"Human card is a {humanCard} of {humanSuit}")

    if map_cards_values[aiCard] != map_cards_values[humanCard]:
        end_game=True
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I see you are using a `while (True)` infinite loop. Using an infinite loop is ok. But this code `while True: continue` will get you stuck forever, because `continue` simply says *go to the next iteration.*
2. Your code that draws the card should be **inside** the `while (True)` loop. Since you like new cards to be drawn in each round.

---

Below is a modified version of your code. Carefully reason through it line-by-line.

```
import random

while True:
  cardValue = random.randint(2,14)
  cardSuit  = random.randint(0,3)
  humanCard = random.randint(2,14)
  humanSuit = random.randint(0,3)

  # do whatever you do to print the cards

  if humanCard > cardValue:
      print ("Human Wins!")
      break # exit while loop
  elif humanCard < cardValue:
      print ("Computer Wins!")
      break # exit while loop
  else: # they draw same card
      print ("It's a draw!")
      # keep going
      while True:
        continue
```

Comment: wouldn't i want the cardValue = random.randint(2,14)

Comment: @Bobnarly You most certainly would. Typo fixed.

Comment: i get this error in python when running my new code TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' in pycharm

Comment: @Bob That means you're trying to compare a `str` (string) with an `int` (integer) which is not allowed. For example, your variable `cardValue` is initially an `int`. But then you do `cardValue = "Ace"`, which changes it to a `str`. This is not recommended.

Comment: should i revert back to printing them, this seems to be a cleaner output

Comment: Sure. So for example, when `humanCard` is an integer `9`, and `cardValue` is a string `'Jack'`, the comparison fails because of incompatible types. Try not doing things like `if cardValue == 14: cardValue = "Ace"`.

Comment: ok so i reverted back to the print ill post the new code, but when its a draw it just outputs "Its a draw!" it doesn't replay the game